# Linq subquery with in a query

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

I have two lists from which I have to get two values(MyCaption and MyValue).

```
List<UserInfoModel> userInfo = new List<UserInfoModel>();

List<myuser_field> myUserFields = GetMyUserFields();
var otherUserFields = otherUserService.GetOtherUserFields();

userInfo = (from otherUserField in otherUserFields
               where otherUserField.Chosen == true 
                    select new UserInfoModel {
                        MyCaption = otherUserField.FieldAlias,
                        MyValue =
                    }).ToList();
```

MyCaption I am directly getting from one of the list. Now to get MyValue I need to find based on otherUserField.FieldName.
i.e I have to find myUserFields.FieldName which is equal to otherUserField.FieldName and assign it to MyValue.

Can it be done in the single query which is as above? Please suggest

Comment: You can use a join with the two collections: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/03/12/joins-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
userInfo = (from myUserField in myUserFields
            join otherUserField in otherUserFields
            on myUserField.FieldName == otherUserField.FieldName
            where otherUserField.Chosen == true 
            select new UserInfoModel {
                MyCaption = otherUserField.FieldAlias,
                MyValue = myUserField.FieldName
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it's not very clear what you want to assign to MyValue.

The following will assign the myuser_field object which has a FieldName that matches the FieldName of the currently enumerated myuser_object (otherUserField.FieldName):

```
List<UserInfoModel> userInfo = new List<UserInfoModel>(); 

List<myuser_field> myUserFields = GetMyUserFields(); 
var otherUserFields = otherUserService.GetOtherUserFields(); 

userInfo = (from otherUserField in otherUserFields 
               where otherUserField.Chosen == true  
                    select new UserInfoModel { 
                        MyCaption = otherUserField.FieldAlias,
                        MyValue = myUserFields.Single(uf => uf.FieldName == otherUserField.FieldName)
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that if there are no or more that one corresponding objects in myUserFields, you'll get an exception. Use SingleOrDefault in place Single, to have null assigned to MyValue in such cases.